# How to convert a Textview array list into a hashset?

Tags: android, arraylist, hashset

Hey stackoverflow community,

i want to send an Arraylist of Textviews through shared Preferences to another Activity, so i tried to convert my list into a HashSet.

This is not accepted:

```
public List<TextView> FavDishes = new ArrayList<TextView>();
```

.
.
.
FavDishes = new ArrayList<>();
            FavDishes.add(eingabe);

```
        **Set<String> taskSet = new HashSet<String>(FavDishes);**
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .edit()
                .putStringSet("Data", taskSet)
                .apply();
```

It tells me: "cannot resolve constructor HashSet on android widget Textview"

How would you solve this Problem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: In a first place, why do you want to do that?

Comment: My App is about a Mensa. I want, that the user is able to add dishes to a "Favourite Dishes" list. So as he scrolls down the and clicks on a dish, he can select there through a button : " add to favourite dishes" gets linked to the list of "Favourite dishes" via a "to favourite dishes button". On the "Favourite dishes" Activity he sees the already added dishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the FavDishes array to get the TextView values as string and store them to an array, then pass that array to your taskset instead of FavDishes.

Code will be something like:

```
List<TextView> FavDishes = new ArrayList<TextView>();
    FavDishes.add(fav1TV);
    FavDishes.add(fav2TV);
    FavDishes.add(fav3TV);


ArrayList<String> FavDishesString = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (TextView FavDish : FavDishes ){
        FavDishesString.add(FavDish.getText().toString());      
    }

    Set<String> taskSet = new HashSet<String>(FavDishesString);
```

Helpful link to ways to iterate arrayList:

https://crunchify.com/how-to-iterate-through-java-list-4-way-to-iterate-through-loop/

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a good solution, could you please write some example code, to make me better understand and implement your advice?

Comment: Sorry, just about to start the BBQ as lunchtime here so can't at the moment, but I might get back to it if no one else posts.

Comment: great! don't hurry. I tried this if (v == save) {
            FavDishes.add(eingabe);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            }
                JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(FavDishes);

            editor.putString("jsondata", jsArray.toString());
            editor.commit();
now, if i go to the activity, where the "eingabe" TextView List should be added, it returns "null", do you know a reason for that? ^^  enjoy your BBQ !

Comment: Thanks great BBQ, I have added some code that should help with the particular issue you asked about. Please accept answer if it does. I read your comment about the overall goal, but rather too broad. So I suggest posting new specifc questions as you progress with your code.